# Create a Note in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, notes

I enabled the Note tool in my Org and I added the relative related lists in Objects Layout. The problem is when I switch in Lightning Experience I can't take the note but only attach file. How Can I take Note in Lightning Experience?

Below an image on Lead Object of Note Related List:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available as a button:

[image]

clicking on it will open a popup:

[image]

And saving this will add your note.

Keep in mind that for displaying the button in your record home, you need to edit your page layout, choose `Salesforce1 and Lightning Actions` and drag and drop the `New Note` button to the `Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions` area:

[image]